# How to reference self entities with Breeze.js

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm using breeze.js in one of my project and I would like to map a graph of selft-related data.
The definition of the metadata are made by hand.
My entity is referencing 2 types (parents and subcats) which are both array of ids of the entity itself.

My first attempt was to build my client metadataStore as following :

```js
function addTransactionCategory() {
        addType({
            name: 'Category',
            dataProperties: {
                id: {type: ID},
                name: {max: 400, nullOk: false},
                description: {max: 400},
                parents: {max: 400}, // This is not correct
                subcats: {max: 400} // This is not correct
            },
            navigationProperties: {
                parents: {type: 'Category', hasMany: true},
                subcats: {type: 'Category', hasMany: true}
            }
        });
    }
```

and here is an example of JSON data as

```
{
    _id: 117,
    name: "Utilities",
    description: "Example of entity",
    subcats: [
       118,
       119,
       120,
       121,
       122,
       123,
       124,
       125
    ],
    parents: [ ]
 }
```

How should I implement this type of relation in Breeze knowing that the navigationProperties is throwing error.  My backend is a MongoDb and I don't want to duplicate the information, that's why I'm using this data schema logic.

---

Based on the comment from @ward I would like to elaborate a bit more on the structure of the model.

From a given category I would like to be able to retrieve all the parents (level x - 1) attached to this category and I want to be able to retrieve the sub-categories (level x+1).

Here is a picture showing on the left an example with relations.
On the right, a table structure if the structure would be designed in SQL.
[example of the entity and SQL tables http://imageshack.com/a/img909/6914/ogeirV.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img909/6914/ogeirV.png)

This example show one level of relation.  The main idea is to have many level of relation.

A category can have 0 or n sub-categories / parents
A sub-category can have 0 or n parents / subcategories
This Structure allow deep structure of many level 
E.g.   Cat A
         → Cat A A
            → Cat A A A
               → Cat A A A A 
                   ...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDb doesn't support relationships between entities.

Breeze does. But you are pretty far off from bridging the gap I'm afraid.

### An example self-referencing type

`Employee` in DocCode is an example of a self-referencing `EntityType`. An employee can have **one manager employee** (parent) and **many direct reports employees** (children).

You can set a break point in one of the Northwind DocCode tests, extract the `Employee` type via `entityManager.metadataStore.getEntityType('Employee')`, and examine the type's data and navigation properties to see how the relationship is structured.

You would find that each Employee's `Manager` property is supported by a `ReportsToEmployeeID` FK property. That's in keeping with the idea that an employee has ONE manager. Breeze uses this FK to maintain the `Manager` and `DirectReports` properties for all employees in cache.

Notice that when an employee is a "manager", it has a "direct reports" navigation but it does not maintain a list of the IDs of those direct report employees. It counts on being able to reconstruct the contents of the `DirectReports`array based on the FKs in the direct report employees.

Now compare this to what you're doing.

### Category has multiple parents

Categories have multiple parents? Really? Are you ***sure this is true of your model***?

That implies a many-to-many relationship between parent categories and child categories. Sorry but Breeze doesn't support many-to-many. You would need intermediate mapping entities to represent the Parent_Child connections. I'll hold off on exploring this possibility until you've had a chance to clarify.

### A Category parent holds the ids of its children

The `Category.subcats` property is an array of ids. This means you expect the parent to hold references to the children rather than have the children hold references to the parent (as `Employee` does with `ReportsToEmployeeID` being the reference to the manager parent).

Sorry, but Breeze isn't set up to work that way.

I *do understand* why you want to store data this way. Mongo is non-relational. To find the sub-categories of Category X you *think* that you don't want to search the Mongo database for all Categories with a `ParentID` of `X._id`.

But what good are those "subcat" IDs to you now? You can't do anything with them directly ... unless all `Category` instances are in cache.

If you can't count on all Categories being in cache, you'll have to retrieve the "subcats" with a query that lists the sub-cat ids. Two problems with that:  (1) it's a more difficult query than a query for "ParentID equal X._id" and (2) it's much harder to maintain this `subcat` array than it would be to maintained the FKs on the child categories. Think what you must do when you reassign a Category from one parent Category to another. That's two update operations and they can't be in the transaction!

### Conclusion

I think before figuring out how to setup the navigation properties in Breeze it is **first necessary to get a better handle on your model and how you intend to maintain and use these relationships in the first place**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  All your comments makes lot of sense.  Please see my edit, maybe the logic i'm trying to put in place will make more sense.  What would be the ideal structure to put in place in Mongo to be able to support a multi-level hierarchy and of course use breeze as this tool is fantastic !